# How to use express.js as proxy in angularjs-seed app

Tags: angularjs, express, cross-domain

> angularjs newbie alert!!!

I need to a proxy to avoid CORS & i'm looking to implement [express-proxy](https://gist.github.com/davemo/4027855). I found this solution but I'm not sure where to put the code. I need the information in the context of a typical angular-seed app.  Please help. Thank you!

ex: Where do I put in the code & how do I start the proxy server

```
var express   = require('express'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    app       = express();

var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();

function apiProxy(host, port) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.url.match(new RegExp('^\/api\/'))) {
      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {host: host, port: port});
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + "/generated"));
  app.use(apiProxy('localhost', 3000));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact setup is, but if you follow the templating from a scaffolding solution like yo, this code would go in the root directory under a file called, let's say, `server.js`. To start the server, to to the directory in the command line and type `node server.js` (or you can use `grunt`as a task runner if it is installed with your project). Lastly, just open your browswer to `localhost:3000` and you should be all good to go.